# MySQL/InnoDB with FK constraints: find tables/rows affected by cascaded delete

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a MySQL/InnoDB database set up with FK constraints. If I delete a row in a 'root' table, the dependent tables will have corresponding rows deleted.

How can I show what has been deleted, or at least which tables have been affected?

Is there any simple way or will I need to write a tool to compare before and after?

Would a replication log show what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to show what was deleted
No, it will not show up in replication log

Only thing I can think of, is to query `information_schema` views to see what tables have FK constraints depending on 'root' table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TABLE_NAME FROM REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE 
  CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'yourDatabase'
  AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'rootTable'
  AND DELETE_RULE = 'CASCADE'
```

Comment: Oh, that's useful! I was already generating that information, but basically from a screen scrape. I didn't know you could get that into from information_screener! Thanks.